# Android Jetpack Compose AdapterList crashing

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am using AdapterList in Android Jetpack Compose. In list I have clickable component. 
 When I start scrolling without untouch and go out of that AdapterList, It's crashing. It might be library issue.

Thanks in Advance.

I am using...

```
 //Jetpack Component

implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev09'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev09'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev09'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-foundation:0.1.0-dev09'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev09'
```

AdapterList

```
AdapterList(data = model.seats, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).fillMaxSize()) { seat ->
                ItemSeat(seat)}
```

ListItem

```
@Composable
fun ItemSeat(seat: Seat) {
Clickable(onClick = {},
    modifier = Modifier.drawBackground(color = colorResource(id = R.color.color_cd3f34))
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(text = "Seat ${seat.no}")
 }
}
```

Crash Logs

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nextorder.pos, PID: 4821
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: LayoutCoordinate operations are only valid when isAttached is true
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.localToRoot(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:169)
        at androidx.ui.core.LayoutNodeWrapper.localToGlobal(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:165)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.PointerInputFilter.getPosition$ui_platform_release(PointerInput.kt:100)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.Node.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:326)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.Node.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:332)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.Node.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:332)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.Node.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:332)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.Node.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:332)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.Node.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:332)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.Node.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:332)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.Node.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:332)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.NodeParent.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:194)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:100)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges$default(HitPathTracker.kt:91)
        at androidx.ui.core.pointerinput.PointerInputEventProcessor.process(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:67)
        at androidx.ui.core.AndroidComposeView.onTouchEvent(AndroidOwner.kt:648)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13471)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3216)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2888)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:754)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3494)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:712)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13719)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of dev15 version, `AdapterList` has been deprecated in favor of `LazyColumnFor`. The issues you pointed should be fixed if you use LazyColumnFor.

Answer (score 1):

It was a known issue and has been fixed in `dev14` (the current version)